# Consulta Base de Datos MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Voy a editar por completo la consulta, tengo una base con la siguiente información:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con dicha tabla estoy buscando contar cuantos asesores tienen una utilidad neta mayor a $30,000 y $3,000. Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT
 ((SELECT COUNT(NOMBRE_USUARIO) FROM VSIGLO WHERE UTILIDAD_NETA > 30000)) AS MAYOR_30K,
 ((SELECT COUNT(NOMBRE_USUARIO) FROM VSIGLO WHERE UTILIDAD_NETA > 3000)) AS MAYOR_3K
```

El resultado de la siguiente consulta me devuelve lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se como hacer la consulta, o subconsulta que me de algo similar a esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo último que intente y que me sugirieron es lo siguiente:

```
SELECT
    NOMBRE_ASESOR
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN UTILIDAD_NETA > 30000 THEN 1 END) MAYOR_30K
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN UTILIDAD_NETA > 3000 THEN 1 END) MAYOR_3K
FROM VSIGLO
GROUP BY NOMBRE_ASESOR
```

Y la salida es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya estoy más cerca, solo me falta quitar los 0 de la columna Mayor_3k para compactar el resultado.

Gracias

Comment: tu estas pidiendo que te cuetan el nº de empleados que cumplen ese requisito pide que te de el nombre quita el count

Comment: ¿El `Nombre_Empleado` esta dentro de la tabla `VSIGLO`?

Comment: Para que recibas una buena respuesta, debes incluir la estructura de las tablas sobre las que consultas, junto con algunos datos de prueba (y la salida esperada, que ya más o menos la describiste).

Comment: @Marcos si el nombre de empleado esta en esa vista! Pero observo mi consulta esta mal porque debo sumar la utilidad neta por producto y empleado que lo ha vendido, y de ahí mostrar el número de productos que la suma sea mayor a 30,000 y 3,000

Comment: @CarlosAlbertoAlcocerJuárez, sigo sin poder determinar cual es campo identificador de empleado

Comment: En la primera imagen nos muestras cuatro columnas que parecen ser de la tabla de ventas ¿la primera de ellas es el ID del vendedor? si no, debes indicar donde está el ID del vendedor (otra columna?)  y el nombre del vendedor (supongo que otra tabla). Tu pregunta no es complicada pero falta información para que podamos ayudarte

Comment: Agrupa por usuario y haz agregación condicional por utilidad.

Comment: Gracias @Sal , lo pude agrupar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

he estado trabajando la query que estás haciendo y solo le agregué un `where`

query:

```
SELECT
nombre_usuario,
COUNT(CASE WHEN utilidad_neta > 3000 THEN 1 END) AS mayor_3k,
COUNT(CASE WHEN utilidad_neta > 30000 THEN 1 END) AS mayor_30k
FROM VSIGLO 
WHERE utilidad_neta > 3000
GROUP BY nombre_usuario
```

aquí estaba mi ejemplo
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9220f9/1

Comment: Gracias! Fue de mucha utilidad tu aportación, Tema Resuelto. Saludos